Shadowmapping: why shadows rotate with the model?
I'm implementing shadowmapping, and it works very well while objects are not rotated. If rotation is applied to an object, the spotlight and the shadow rotate with it.
screenshot with problem highlighted
same scene, same light position, but sun is rotated
To clarify, there is a single light source in the scene, and the expected result is that all planets are lit like the sun in picture 1.
My code is based on this webgpu sample, i tried rotating the object instead of the camera in this sample, by applying rotation to modelMatrix, and shadows seem to work fine. I just can`t see what i am missing.
Here is my vertexShadow.wgsl code:
alias float4 = vec4<f32>;
alias float3 = vec3<f32>;
alias float2 = vec2<f32>;

struct VertexInput {
 @location(0) position: float3,
};

struct ViewParams {
 camera_projection_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
 camera_view_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
 camera_position: vec4f,
 light_projection_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
 light_view_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
 light_position: vec4f
};

struct NodeParams {
 transform: mat4x4<f32>,
};

@group(0) @binding(0)
var<uniform> view_params: ViewParams;

@group(1) @binding(0)
var<uniform> node_params: NodeParams;

@vertex
fn vertex_main(vert: VertexInput) -> @builtin(position) vec4f {
 let light_view_projection_matrix = view_params.light_projection_matrix * view_params.light_view_matrix;

 return light_view_projection_matrix * node_params.transform * float4(vert.position, 1.0);
};

And here is my testShader.wgsl:
alias float4 = vec4<f32>;
alias float3 = vec3<f32>;
alias float2 = vec2<f32>;

struct VertexInput {
    @location(0) position: float3,
    @location(1) texcoords: float2,
    @location(2) normal: float3
};

struct VertexOutput {
    @builtin(position) position: float4,
    @location(0) world_position: float3,
    @location(1) texcoords: float2,
    @location(2) normal: float3,
    @location(3) camera_position: float3,
    @location(4) shadow_position: vec3f
};

struct ViewParams {
    camera_projection_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
    camera_view_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
    camera_position: vec4f,
    light_projection_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
    light_view_matrix: mat4x4<f32>,
    light_position: vec4f
};

struct NodeParams {
    transform: mat4x4<f32>,
};

struct MaterialParams {
    base_color_factor: float4,
    metallic_factor: f32,
    roughness_factor: f32,
};

@group(0) @binding(0)
var<uniform> view_params: ViewParams;

@group(1) @binding(0)
var<uniform> node_params: NodeParams;

@group(2) @binding(0)
var<uniform> material_params: MaterialParams;

@group(3) @binding(1)
var base_color_sampler: sampler;

@group(2) @binding(1)
var base_color_texture: texture_2d<f32>;

@group(3) @binding(2)
var metallic_roughness_sampler: sampler;

@group(2) @binding(2)
var metallic_roughness_texture: texture_2d<f32>;

@group(3) @binding(3)
var tangent_normal_sampler: sampler;

@group(2) @binding(3)
var tangent_normal_texture: texture_2d<f32>;

@group(3) @binding(4)
var shadow_sampler: sampler_comparison;

@group(2) @binding(4)
var shadow_texture: texture_depth_2d;

const ambientFactor = 0.1;


@vertex
fn vertex_main(vert: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;

    let light_view_projection_matrix = view_params.light_projection_matrix * view_params.light_view_matrix;
    let camera_view_projection_matrix = view_params.camera_projection_matrix * view_params.camera_view_matrix;
    let position_from_light = light_view_projection_matrix * node_params.transform * float4(vert.position, 1.0);

    out.shadow_position = vec3(
        position_from_light.xy * vec2(0.5, -0.5) + vec2(0.5),
        position_from_light.z
    );
    out.position = camera_view_projection_matrix * node_params.transform * float4(vert.position, 1.0);
    out.world_position = out.position.xyz;
    out.texcoords = vert.texcoords;
    out.normal = vert.normal;
    out.camera_position = view_params.camera_position.xyz;

    return out;
};

fn linear_to_srgb(x: f32) -> f32 {
    if (x <= 0.0031308) {
        return 12.92 * x;
    }
    return 1.055 * pow(x, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055;
}

fn decode_color(color: vec4f) -> vec4f {
    return vec4f(linear_to_srgb(color.x), linear_to_srgb(color.y), linear_to_srgb(color.z), 1.0);
}

@fragment
fn fragment_main(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) float4 {
    let albedoColor = decode_color(
        textureSample(base_color_texture, base_color_sampler, in.texcoords) 
            * material_params.base_color_factor
    );

    var visibility = 0.0;
    let oneOverShadowDepthTextureSize = 1.0 / 1024.0;
    for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        for (var x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
            let offset = vec2f(vec2(x, y)) * oneOverShadowDepthTextureSize;

            visibility += textureSampleCompare(
                shadow_texture, shadow_sampler,
                in.shadow_position.xy + offset, in.shadow_position.z - 0.007
            );
        }
    }
    
    visibility /= 9.0;

    let lambertFactor = max(dot(normalize(view_params.light_position.xyz - in.world_position), normalize(in.normal)), 0.0);

    let lightingFactor = min(ambientFactor + visibility * lambertFactor, 1.0);

    return vec4(lightingFactor * albedoColor.xyz, 1.0);
};


Please explain what you mean with "models are (not) rotated", "shadow rotates with it". Or show a [mre].
